# Find Jersey Parent Path

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey 2.x endpoint that a user can POST to to update a specific property on a parent resource. On success, I would like to return a 303 status and specify the path to the parent resource in the `Location` header.

eg. if the user POSTed to:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/resource/field
```

then set the location header in the response to:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/resource
```

It seems like there should be a straightforward way to do this with `UriInfo`/`UriBuilder`, but I'm at a loss as to how to do it without hard-coding something that's likely to break later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the base URI (which assuming is `http://example.com/api`) from [`UriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getBaseUriBuilder%28%29), then append the `XxxResource` path with [`builder.path(XxxResource.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#path%28java.lang.Class%29).

Then from the built `URI`, return [`Response.seeOther(uri).build();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther%28java.net.URI%29).  Complete example:

```
@Path("/v1/resource")
public class Resource {

    @GET
    public Response getResource() {
        return Response.ok("Hello Redirects!").build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/field")
    public Response getResource(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        URI resourceBaseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
            .path(Resource.class)
            .build();
        return Response.seeOther(resourceBaseUri).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use path(Resource.class, "methodName") to get the path to a specific method on a resource, but I guess that only returns the method relative to the containing resource. Adding in path(Resource.class) got me what I needed.